# 2-10x Slower Deployments with Winter '15?

Tags: apex, deployment, winter15

We've recently had deployments spike in several of the client orgs we work with. The worst example jumping from 45 minutes to upwards of 7 hours. A current deployment is 3 hours in and has only completed 30 out of 487 tests. In all cases deployment times are highly variable, but are always nearly double what they use to be, and in some cases are a whole order of magnitude slower.

Does anyone know what changed that would lead to this? Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: I didn't notice any slowness in our Winter15 orgs so far.. maybe you can try raising a case with SF  mentioning the instance / org details and deployment times and see if they can find anything..

Comment: is there any pattern in which instances this is happening in? I haven't seen anything like this in the EU and CS instances I work with.

Comment: Are you on NA2? We are seeing the same issue on that instance, but not on other instances.

Comment: we've logged a case with sfdc support, some individual tests say they are taking 30 minutes to complete which is pretty insane, the worst offender is on na3, but also seeing behavior on na5

Comment: will post back anything i here from sfdc support

Comment: I witnessed 4x slower on na4 instance.

Comment: NA10 is pretty horrible, as well.  I have one test pushing 45 minutes (used to take between 20-30 seconds, nearly 100x the time).  I had to notch it down from 200 test records to 1 in that test method simply to get it to not fail and allow deployments to succeed (but that kills my ability to test for scale/bulkification!)

Comment: still waiting for support, case #11192114, been a week now, with no actionable response and we actually have premier support

Answer (score 9):

Working on closing the question I just posted as a duplicate ([Test Execution Slowness](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55294/test-execution-slowness)):

> Anyone else experience a major slowdown in test execution? I have
>   approximately 300 test methods that I run daily. What used to take
>   40-60 minutes now takes 2-3 hours, and the slowness is also causing
>   inbound changesets to fail since some now exceed the time limit
>   allowed. I've run the "slow" tests in the sandbox and they run in well
>   under 60 seconds, so there's no issue with the test classes
>   themselves...
>
> Anyone else having this issue?

Short answer, yes, I'm in the exact same boat.

UPDATE:

After waiting several days for a response on my ticket, I received a polite "f off" since I don't have upgraded support.  I hope someone else is able to get this actually prioritized.

> We have developed a new channel for Salesforce customers and partners
>   who have not purchased Premier Success plans to receive answers to
>   their developer support questions and to receive assistance if they
>   have run into a bug or platform issue.
>
> Standard customers and basic partners are being directed to the
>   developer support boards at https://developer.salesforce.com/.
>
> Salesforce technical support staffs resources that now do the
>   following:
>
> 1) Ensure all developer support posts receive a response  2) Monitor
>   posts for possible platform bugs and issues not related to customer or
>   partner code 3) Log support cases for confirmed issues and drive to
>   resolution through normal support processes
>
> Please help us educate our customers and partners that they now have a
>   channel available to them that did not exist before. Please help them
>   understand that we will help them and we will open support cases for
>   bugs or issues with the platform.
>
> Salesforce Customers can receive more information about our premier
>   success plans here:
>   http://www.salesforce.com/services-training/customer-support/
>
> Salesforce partners can receive more information regarding Partner
>   Developer Support which gives them the ability to log developer
>   support cases, as well as all the success plans available to partners,
>   here:
>   http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_PartnerSupport.pdf

UPDATE:

An internal salesforce chatter feed says that WINTER '15 PATCH 13.0 will be released today!

Comment: My case was escalated to R&D.  They seem to be aware of the issue.  It sounds like you never made it to someone who was able/willing to check if there is an open R&D investigation.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I was actually pushed to R&D by my sales rep.  The response above was from R&D, sadly...

Comment: we've got a known issue https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XJg

Comment: Wow, good job salesforce, way to take the bull by the horns.  "SCHEDULED - SPRING '15"...  I would love to be deploying things glacially slow for the next 3-4 months!  I am not amused...

Comment: Better: "SCHEDULED - WINTER '15 PATCH 13.0" ... now anyone know when patch 13.0 will be released?

Comment: An internal salesforce chatter feed says that WINTER '15 PATCH 13.0 will be released today!

Comment: @NathanWilliams see the recent answer/comment from Daniel, turns out it's not going out until patch 15.0, and was erroneously marked as fixed today

Answer (score 4):

I also have a case open with Salesforce for this issue as well.  My case number is 11182795 if you want to reference it.   I have a single test that is taking almost an hour to run!  Interestingly, the same tests run perfectly fine through the Apex Test Execution in the setup UI.  This definitely started some time over the weekend since deployments on Friday took about 20 minutes and now they are up to 2 hours.

Update:  SF says:  "I've reviewed your case and would like to inform you that we're having an ongoing issue related to change-set validation/deployment time which R&D is working on with high priority. We'll confirm first internally if you're also impacted by that and then take further action on your case."

Comment: I submitted a ticket a few hours ago and referenced this thread.

Comment: Any chance they gave you a link to a known issue? Also, did they imply it's just change sets? I've been seeing slowness with both, but change sets has been far worse than ant/eclipse deployments.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the Salesforce Known Issue (https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XJgAAM) reporting this as fixed, it most assuredly is not.

I found this out the hard way, by trying a change set and seeing the still awfully slow deployment times.

I have confirmed this with Salesforce support, this was apparently marked as 'FIXED' erroneously, and is scheduled for Winter 15 Patch 15.0, not Patch 13.0 as the Known Issue states.

I would have just left this as a comment to another answer, but I don't have the required reputation to do so.

EDIT: Salesforce have provided an update on the Known Issue: [10-Dec-2014: This issue is not fixed, despite what it says at the top of this page. The "red Xs" show the real status.]

Answer (score 0):

I've got a case open with support, 11192114, and they performed some trace logging on a change set that took over 17 hours to deploy, a new record considering deployments were under half an hour a month ago.

They've acknowledged there is an issue with change sets, but have yet to provide any more details on it. I'm working to get this up as a known issue, so we can all register it's affecting us.

In the meantime, ant or eclipse based deployments, while still slower than usual, or only 2-4x slower than usual, and far faster than change set deployments which are taking 10x+ times longer.

Answer (score -1):

A viable Workaround is to use Eclipse IDE until the issue is resolved.

Comment: I've been having issues with ant/eclipse as well, although change sets do appear to take noticeably longer. With ant i'm see 2-4x the usual time, change sets was 2-10+ times the usual time.

Comment: Varun it always adds quality to an answer if you elaborate a bit. Go into detail about your experience or reference documentation relevant to the question and your answer.