# Test Execution Slowness

Tags: apex, unit-test

Anyone else experience a major slowdown in test execution?  I have approximately 300 test methods that I run daily.  What used to take 40-60 minutes now takes 2-3 hours, and the slowness is also causing inbound changesets to fail since some now exceed the time limit allowed.  I've run the "slow" tests in the sandbox and they run in well under 60 seconds, so there's no issue with the test classes themselves...

Anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I am having exactly the same issue on NA2.  It seems to have started after this weekend.  I just deployed a change set that took 3 hours when it used to take 20 min.  What instance are you on?  I checked a customer org on NA8 and it was fine.  Support has not been very helpful and simply says there is no SLA for deployments.  I am pushing back on them, but I am glad to see we are not alone.

Comment: I share the thought that it was something that happened this weekend...  I'm on NA10.  I have a changeset that is currently well over 5 hours and I expect to see a "time limit" failure or two at the end just to add salt to the wound.